# update first line of table in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

`Corresp` which have this columns: `idCorresp, textCorresp ,dateCorresp`
`Trans` which have this columns: `idTransf , textTransf, dateTransf,idCorresp`

this is an example of data:

**Corresp**:

```
001, testCorresp, 01/01/2014
```

**Trans**

```
1 , T1, 01/01/2013, 001
2 , T2, 01/02/2013, 001
3 , T3, 01/03/2013, 001
```

I want to develop a query with postgres to modify just the first line of the table `trans`  which is related to the table `corresp`

so make `textCorresp`  of `Corresp`  in this column : `textTransf` of the first line of Trans`

I try without success  with:

```
update Trans trans
set textTransf= (
select corresp.textCorresp 
from Corresp corresp , Trans trans
where corresp.idCorresp= trans.idCorresp
)
from Corresp corresp , Trans trans
where corresp.idCorresp= trans.idCorresp
and trans.dateTransf=(select min(trans.dateTransf) 
from Corresp corresp , Trans trans
where corresp.idCorresp= trans.idCorresp)
```

as a result after running my query I want to have this result in `Trans`

```
1 , testCorresp, 01/01/2013, 001
2 , T2, 01/02/2013, 001
3 , T3, 01/03/2013, 001
```

I try also with :

```
update Trans trans3
    set textTransf= 
textCorresp 
from 
(
select Corresp .textCorresp ,  min(trans.dateTransf)   
from Trans trans , Corresp corresp, Trans trans2
where corresp.idCorresp= trans.idCorresp
and corresp.idCorresp= trans2.idCorresp
group by 
corresp.textCorresp ,trans.dateTransf
)as toto

WHERE  trans3.idTransf = toto.idTransf
```

Comment: First of all - how do you define the `just the first line of the table trans`? Is it the line with minimal date? A line with minimal id? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

This is the general idea.

```
update trans
set this = that, etc
where idtransf = 
(select min(idtransf)
from trans
where idCorresp = the one you want)
```

**Edit starts here**

For the new requirement, this will work with many db engines.  Hopefully postgresql is one of them.

```
update trans
field = sqfield
from trans join 
(select SomeFieldFromTrans sqlfield, min(idtransf) mintrans
from trans join corresp on the proper fields
group by SomeFieldFromTrans ) sq ob idtransf = mintrans
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I have updated my question,  I want to run my query not in specific Corresp and Transf  but for all data in this two tables

Comment: At work, when someone changes a requirement after I've satisfied it, they owe me a beer.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try like this

```
update Trans set textTransf = (select textCorresp from Corresp cr join Trans tx
on cr.idCorresp = tx.idCorresp)
where idTransf = (
select idTransf 
from 
Trans t join Corresp c
on t.idCorresp = c.idCorresp limit 1
)
```